# HTTPS Frontend and backend

Tags: magento-1.9, https

I have enabled HTTPS on both backend and frontend. 
Problem is on the back-end the https works fine *(green lock)* but on the front end i have https BUT i have a **grey lock** icon which is described as " not fully secure".

How can the https fully work on back-end and partially work on front-end ? 
And how can i resolve this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: examine your site in Chrome's browser console, it will tell you which files are still coming from http instead of https.

Comment: please check static block and page content in the back-end. In that, maybe you have added direct HTTP URL(s). If you found URL(s) with HTTP in static content then just replace them HTTPS.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers ill try that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there are some resource which you added in your static block has direct URL and has only `HTTP` with it

go to page and right click and click on `view page source`

and find `http:` check that resource and try to replace them with `Https`

and once you have all resource with `HTTPS` then green icon will come

Hope this info helps you

Answer (score 0):

Go to : `System > Configuration > Web > Secure` and make sure the following are set correctly :

- Base Link URL - `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL - `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL - `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base Javascript URL - `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

With this, the paths generated will follow `"Base URL"`.  If a page is secure everything on it will also be served secure.

Check also your frontend links whether they are in https, images, icones, links etc...